# How can I switch in and out of NERDtree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is there a way to switch in and out of NERDtree -- mouse disabled? I know I can press 'q' to quit NERDtree and go back to text editor, but when I go back to NERDtree it doesn't keep track of which directories I had pressed open before, and I would like to keep the list of directories open. I referenced NERDtree help, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. Perhaps I missed something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NERDTree opens as a sidebar next to the existing open windows. You can therefore use all Vim window movement commands to jump back and forth.

For example, `<C-W>p` (that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>P</kbd>) goes back to the previous window, and `1<C-W><C-W>` goes to the first window (which usually is the leftmost split NERDTree). You'll find the whole list at `:help window-move-cursor`; for effective window handling, it's important you know these very well.

Answer (score 4):

As a potential best practice , I map `F2` key to toggle NERDTree.

```
map <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let NERDTreeWinSize=32
let NERDTreeWinPos="left"
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1
let NERDTreeAutoDeleteBuffer=1
let NERDTreeAutoDeleteBuffer=1
```

And also, I map `Ctrl+j/k/hl` to quickly move between opened vim windows.

```
"Smart way to move between windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l
```

Answer (score 3):

To switch between the NERDtree "window" and the text "window" with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and then <kbd>right arrow</kbd>

and then to go back I use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and then <kbd>left arrow</kbd>

For more info on "vim windows"

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html

Comment: Using the cursor keys is rather ineffective and unusual for Vim. Fortunately, the home-row alternatives `<C-w>l` and `<C-w>h` work as well.

Comment: Plus on MacOS these keys cycle through the desktops available.